# Ответ на сообщения БОТ

Tags: python, telegram

Боту отправлю сообщение "номера телефона". Сохраняю ID сообщения в глобальную переменную. Ответ от бота приходит с кнопками Inline(Новый номер? Да НЕТ). Если нажимаю "ДА". То бот отправляет еще одно сообщение Регистрация прошла? и кнопка Inline ("Готов"). после нажатия на кнопку готов, бот сообщает что Номер телефона который был в первом сообщении ЗАРЕГИТСРОВАН. Всё отлично работает, до тех пор пока между сообщения не появляется еще обдно с номером телефона. И тогда ID сообщения1 затирается ID сообщением2 , т.к. переменная глобальная. Вопрос как разделить реакции на эти два сообщения? Может делать список, где храниться ID сообщений? Подскажите чтоб не городить костыли.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import logging
import config
import re

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

API_TOKEN = config.TelegramAPI

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
buttons = [
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Да", callback_data="yes"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нет", callback_data="no"),
    ]
button2 = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Готов", callback_data="finish")]
inline_kb_full = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
inline_kb_full.add(*buttons)
inline_kb_ok = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
inline_kb_ok.add(*button2)
tel = ''
global id_mes
regexp_tel = '^(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}'



@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет!\nЭто бот!\n Скоро я буду работать.")

@dp.message_handler(regexp=regexp_tel)
async def driver_new(message: types.Message):
   
    global tel
    global id_mes

    id_mes = message.message_id
    tel = re.match(regexp_tel, message.text).group(0)
    await message.answer(f"{tel} Это новый номер?",  reply_markup=inline_kb_full)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'finish')
async def about_bot_message(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    await call.message.delete()
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat['id'], f'Номер {tel}\n<b>Зарегистрирован!</b>', parse_mode="HTML", reply_to_message_id=id_mes)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'yes')
async def yes_bot_message(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat['id'], f"Отлично", reply_markup=inline_kb_ok)    
    await call.message.delete()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'no')
async def no_bot_message(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    await call.message.delete()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Возможно, Вам нужно хранить словарь, где ключ - id пользователя, а ключ - номер телефона. Также можете словарь заменить датой базой, например: sqlite.

Comment: решил добавлять  callback_data=f"finish {id_mes} {tel}" , а потом распарсить